# How to update a field where another field equals a particular string

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table called tbltooling.

In it is a field named Part Description (containing various part descriptions), and a field named CategoryID (containing nothing yet).

What I want to do is place a number 1 everywhere in the table where the part description equals "plastic box".

I added an update query having the following code. I'm getting a syntax error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
UPDATE Copy Of TBLTOOLING
SET CategoryID = '1' 
WHERE [Part Description] = "plastic box"
```

Comment: What is `Copy Of TBLTOOLING`?

Comment: ALL CAPS in the title is interpreted as SHOUTING. Please fix.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do this as a query? That way you get the latest answer every time you run the query without changing any DB tables. The data already exists and I don't see how adding the `1` adds anything of value to your data.

Answer (score 0):

It will be, as I assume CategoryID to be numeric:

```sql
UPDATE [Copy Of TBLTOOLING] 
SET CategoryID = 1 
WHERE [Part Description] = "plastic box"
```

or:

```sql
UPDATE TBLTOOLING
SET CategoryID = 1 
WHERE [Part Description] = "plastic box"
```